# How to convert String to Image (Java)

Tags: java, string, image

I have an issue about my Application in detail.
 - I have a java servlet receive data from mms gateway (MM7 protocol) 
I get inputstream (image content , message content ) convert to string

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//String orgin = new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),"UTF-8");
String orgin = Streams.asString(request.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");
```

Then I substring orgin for image content and convert to base64 and save to image file
but string that I convert to base64 can not save to image because this error

```
not a jpeg file
```

I print out  string base64  does not start with /9j that mean not jpg format

please suggest or give an example for me

Best reqard

lieang noob noob

sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 2):

This is at least part of your problem:

```
String orgin = Streams.asString(request.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");
```

You shouldn't be converting it into a string to start with. It's binary data, right? So read it *from the stream as binary data*.

Now it sounds like you basically want to get separate "chunks" of that binary data - but converting the data into a string format to start with is *not* appropriate, unless that binary data really is encoded text.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this might help: http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Encoding of image is very simple.

Encoding Source:

```
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

Decoding Source:

```
    byte[] decodedString;
        decodedString = Base64.decode(picture, Base64.DEFAULT);

        imageView1.setImageBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code the for the String to Image 
here "origin" is a String

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


byte[] imgByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(origin);
FileOutputStream imgOutFile = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Workspaces\\String_To_Image.jpg");
imgOutFile.write(imgByteArray);
imgOutFile.close();
```